# How to change a column width on WooCommerce orders page (Admin)

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to increase the column width for 'Ship to' in WooCommerce plugin orders page (Admin). So far, I have tried adding the CSS rules in header as well as I have tried JS solutions but nothing works. Here is the `td` I'm trying to modify:
`<td class="shipping_address column-shipping_address" data-colname="Ship to">`

Can anyone please help me where is the template for orders listing page in WoCommerce WordPress plugin? I want to add the rules directly in the template file. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set a different column width for the *Ship to*, add this to your `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'admin_head', 'wpse_237354_ship_to_column' );

function wpse_237354_ship_to_column() {
    global $pagenow;
    if ( $pagenow == 'edit.php' ) {
        ?>
        <style type="text/css">
          .manage-column.column-shipping_address {
               width: 10px;
           }
         </style>
        <?php
    }
}
```

This adds custom CSS in the header page with your new column width. Just change `width: 10px` to your new size.

Comment: @rehmat Glad to help